# Only show Grand Total - Pivot Table - Excel

Tags: excel

When I do a pivot table, I would like the table to only show ( as result) the grand total row (therefore just 1 row).

Any solution for that?

I have been looking for a solution for a while, but I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Is there a reason you need a pivot table for this, instead of a simple range or table?

Comment: I have 12 columns and 6,000 rows of data. Within those columns some are dates, where 1 date = 1 person. I want to count the number of dates to then get the number of persons. I get the end result in the pivot table but I only need the grand total and not the thousands of dates before that.I do a pivot table, because then I create a dashboard with filters etc..